# Reduce size of Feynman diagram

Tags: diagrams, size, feynman

is it possible to reduce the size of this diagram?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynman}
        \vertex(d1) {\(d\)}; 
        \vertex[right=5cm of d1] (u1) {\(u\)};
        \vertex[above right=0.7cm and 1.5cm of d1] (v1);
        \vertex[above right=1cm and 1cm of v1] (v2);
        \vertex[above right=0.5cm and 1cm of v2] (nu) {$\bar\nu_e$};
        \vertex[below right=0.5cm and 1cm of v2] (e) {$e^-$};
        \vertex[below=2em of d1] (u2) {\(u\)}; 
        \vertex[below=2em of u1] (u3) {\(u\)};
        \vertex[below=2em of u2] (d2) {\(d\)}; 
        \vertex[right=5cm of d2] (d3) {\(d\)};
        \diagram* { {[edges=fermion]
                (d1) -- [thick] (v1) -- [thick] (u1), (nu) -- [thick] (v2) -- [thick] (e),
                 (u2) -- [thick] (u3), (d2) -- [thick] (d3) 
            },
            (v1) -- [boson, edge label=\(W^-\), thick] (v2)
        }; 
        \draw [decoration={brace}, decorate, thick] (d2.south west) -- (d1.north west) node [pos=0.5, left] {\(n\)};
        \draw [decoration={brace}, decorate, thick] (u1.north east) --  (d3.south east) node [pos=0.5, right] {\(p\)};
    \end{feynman} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!